# How To Prevent Automatic Sorting On Primary Key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tablesorter

I want to save my data in table order by time that they insert, but in SQL Server they will order by primary key.

What can I do ?

Comment: When you select data it orders by whatever your `ORDER BY` says. Don't assume it will order by the primary key. What are you _really_ trying to do here?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid . . . SQL Server automatically uses the primary key as the clustered index for the data.  So the data is actually ordered by the primary key on the data pages (a query retrieving it will not return it in this order).  In order words, the language may be a bit awkward, but this is a very valid question.  As I read it, it is not about "ordering" in a query; it is about a clustered index.

Comment: Table order isn't a thing. It doesn't exist. It's made up in your head. There is no such thing as table order. If you want insert order, use an identity column or timestamp column and make that the clustered index (primary key). And even then, **don't trust it**, because Sql Server is free to use the most efficient order for showing results, which in the case of a JOIN, GROUP BY, or query that can be completed entirely from an index (and other reasons) might not be clustered index order anymore. _Table Order does not exist!_

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn i know you are right . my English is not good so i tried so sent my meaning..sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two factors here which you may be confounding; the *physical* ordering of the data (i.e how your computer literally prints the bits onto your hard drive) and the *logical* ordering.

The physical ordering is always defined by your *clustered index*. 9 times out of 10, this also happens to be your primary key, but it doesn't have to be. Think of "Clustered Index" as "How it's physically sorted on my disk". You want it stored a different way, change how you "cluster" it (by the way, if you don't have a clustered index, that's called a "heap", and it doesn't guarantee the physical order of the data).

The *logical* ordering however, does not exist. SQL is based on relational algebra, and relational algebra operates on mathematical sets. The definition of a set contains *no information* about the inherent ordering of the set, only it's constituents.

Now when you query data out, you can specify an `order by` which will return the data to you in the order you asked for. However by default, there is no guarantee or assumption of any ordering (even that of how it's physically stored on disk; even if it happens to return in that order from time to time).

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make the date/time the primary key then, which is a bad idea. If the table has an auto-incrementing primary key then it will always be in that order when you view the table.  But in the end, it really doesn't matter how it is stored, because when you query the table you can order it any way you wish.

Just add a ORDER BY  ASC/DESC

Comment: tnx for answer but i dont have any date or time column. I've used Java DB before and it was ok with that but now i using sql server

Comment: I don't know about Java DB, but it doesn't look like a relational database like SQL Server.  To accomplish what you want you would have to add a date/time field to your table.

Comment: you think its i good idea to add a auto generate integer column like sort_id and select with order by sort_id ?  i try it . it works . but its a good way ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making the primary key an identity column:

```
create table t (
    t_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

This will do exactly what you want.  By default, SQL Server clusters tables on the primary key, and an identity column increments with each update.  Note that although the data pages are sorted, the results of a query are still in arbitrary order, unless you use an `order by` clause in the query.

Such an identity column is much more efficient for inserts than an arbitrary key.  You can make the key you have now `unique` and `not null` -- all the good benefits of a primary key, without the bad effects of having to re-arrange the data pages on each insert (the unique index is a different matter).

The *default* behavior of SQL Server is to cluster the data using the primary key.  You can override this.  For example, this makes `not_pk` the clustered index:

```
create table t (
  id uniqueidentifier primary key default newid(),
  created_at datetime default getdate(),
  not_pk int identity(1, 1) unique clustered 
);
```

I would not use just the `created_at` value as the clustered index -- you might insert more than one row at a given point in time.

Or, you can remove the clustering from the primary key explicitly:

```
create table t (
  id uniqueidentifier primary key nonclustered default newid(),
  created_at datetime default getdate() 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use ORDER BY to on your selects if you want a specific ordering.**

By database theory definition the rows in a table are not sorted. You need to specify the sort order using ORDER BY when retrieving thw rows (using a SELECT).

Now, if you don't specify the ORDER BY and just trust that SQL Server returns them by PK you can be for a big surprise, since this is not safe. By default SQL Server does this since the tables are clustered. But... if later on someone changes the clustering of the table or removes it, all your queries without ORDER BY are going to be wrong, right away. Yep, you could be in trouble.

**So again, please use ORDER BY to on your selects if you want a specific ordering.**